# WPF - XAML binding with nested classes

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following class structure.

```cs
 class A
 {
     List<B> B = new List<B>();
 }

 class B
 {
     List<C> C = new List<C>();
 }
 class C
 {
 }
```

I'm following MVVM pattern. I have an Observable collection created from the objects of class A in my view model.
I need to bind it to my view (WPF) like in the following.

```
        Header 1 ( class A)   * Item 1 ( class C)
                              * Item 2  (class C)
                              * Item 3  ( class C)
                              * Item 1  ( class C)

        Header 2  (class A)   * Item 1 ( class C)
                              * Item 2  (class C)
                              * Item 3   (class C)
                              * Item 4 ( class C)
```

Is this something possible ? If it is, can someone pls help me to bind it to the view ?
Actually, it's not possible to alter the class structure. Having it in that way is a must, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll have to make properties of it:

```cs
 public class A
 {
     List<B> B = new List<B>() { get; set; }
 }

 public class B
 {
     List<C> C = new List<C>() { get; set; }
 }

 public class C
 {
 }
```

After that, you can create an `ItemsControl` in your view to generate the view you'd like to see for each `C`. For more information about the ItemsControl, I forward you to MSDN (I'm not going to create the whole application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In your case you'll need two itemscontrols, one for your B-objects and one for your C-objects.